# Ionic push notification : Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello I am new to Ionic.
I want to use ionic push notification for android phone.

I followed all the instruction from [ionic website](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-android-setup)

For the debugging, I typed `ionic serve`

And I saw

**"Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined"**

in Chrome console.

Of course, notification is not working.

**What am I missing ?**

Any comment would be very helpful.Thank you.

**Below is What I have done**

I have put below code in terminal

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client

ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push

ionic io init
```

My ionic config info

```
dev_push is false,

There is 'app_id'

There is 'api_key'

There is 'gcm_key'
```

NodeJS
v5.2.0 (I tried also v4.2.2)

Ionic cli
v1.7.12

Below code is in `$ionicPlatform.ready`

```
var io = Ionic.io();

        var user = Ionic.User.current();

        if (!user.id) {
          user.id = Ionic.User.anonymousId();
        };

        // Just add some dummy data..
        user.set('name', 'moka');
        user.set('bio', 'This is my little bio');
        user.save();

        var push = new Ionic.Push({
          "onNotification": function(notification) {
            alert('Received push notification!');
          },
          "pluginConfig": {
            "android": {
              "iconColor": "#0000FF"
            }
          }
        });


        var callback = function(data) {
          push.addTokenToUser(user);
          user.save();
        };


        push.register(callback);
```

---

### // Edit

I changed form

```
ionic config set dev_push false
```

to

```
ionic config set dev_push true
```

It does not show no longer

**"Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined"**

However I am not sure if it's correct way.
Because it was written on [this tutorial](https://devdactic.com/android-push-notifications/)

> to turn off your development mode

```
ionic push --google-api-key your-google-api-key
ionic config set gcm_key your-gcm-project-number
ionic config set dev_push false
```

So it does not matter "Uncaught ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined", if I want to test on real android device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not matter.

In fact as you have mentioned `dev_push` must be false while testing it out in real devices.

You can either  set it false manually `ionic config set dev_push false` or not mention it anywhere(by default it is false) :)

Answer (score 1):

Cordova & Phonegap plugins only work on emulators and devices. They will not work on any broswers.

Although with Ionic you can mute those errors a good practice could be to wrap your code like this:

```
if (typeof PushNotification === "defined") {
   // your code here
}
```

This way it wont throw any errors when you write BDD or E2E tests.

You can also add your code inside the:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this error following:

1. `ionic remove ionic-platform-web-client`
2. `cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push`
3. `ionic add ionic-platform-web-client`
4. `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push`
5. `ionic io init`